# docker/fig: port forwarding to guest machine does not work on MacOS

Tags: docker, fig

I am trying to get this fig image here up and running: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/harbur/sonarqube/

docker and fig installed fine and also the two images boot normally (including the applications - checked from the logs). 
however, there should be a port forwarding setup so that I can connect from my host machine to the sonarqube instance. however, I can't connect to the machines as no port is open on the host OS.

Is there anybody who can give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,
Matthias

```
$ docker port dockersonarqube_sonarqube_1
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49154
9000/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:9000
$ curl 127.0.0.1:9000
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:9000; Connection refused
```

this is the fig config file:

```
postgresql:
  image: orchardup/postgresql:latest
  environment:
    - POSTGRESQL_USER=sonar
    - POSTGRESQL_PASS=xaexohquaetiesoo
    - POSTGRESQL_DB=sonar
  volumes:
    - /opt/db/sonarqube/:/var/lib/postgresql
sonarqube:
  image: harbur/sonarqube:latest
  links:
    - postgresql:db
  environment:
    - DB_USER=sonar
    - DB_PASS=xaexohquaetiesoo
    - DB_NAME=sonar
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
    - "443"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `boot2docker` on a Mac, you need to access the website via the VM. You'll need to do two things:

- Expose the VM port on all interfaces by changing `"127.0.0.1:9000:9000"` to `"0.0.0.0:9000:9000"`.
- Use the IP of the VM to connect to the server e.g. `curl $(boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null):9000`

You shouldn't need to muck with port forwarding inside the VM unless you really don't like using the boot2docker IP rather than 0.0.0.0.

Comment: `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile is just a hint. It changes the behavior of `PublishAllPorts` and `Links` options of [`/containers/create` API endpoint](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#create-a-container), but its lack doesn't prevent from exposing ports using `PortBindings` option. And Fig seems to [just pass](https://github.com/docker/fig/blob/master/compose/service.py#L331) all `ports` from .yml config directly to `/containers/create` endpoint. So I don't see how the lack of `EXPOSE` instruction in Dockerfile can prevent Fig from exposing specified ports.

Comment: See [examples section of `docker run`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#examples_8). Especially this: "`$ sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 ubuntu bash`: This binds port 8080 of the container to port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of the host machine. `$ sudo docker run --expose 80 ubuntu bash`: This exposes port 80 of the container for use within a link without publishing the port to the host system's interfaces". The `ubuntu` base image obviously doesn't `EXPOSE` port 80.

Comment: You can test it yourself :)

Comment: Anyway, the output of `docker port` provided in the question tells that the port actually _gets_ exposed: `9000/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:9000`.

Comment: So it seems like a problem with the configuration of SonarCube. Unfortunately, I have no experience with this software to suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: @sam.kozin yeah, you seem to be right. I would argue the EXPOSE documentation is misleading at best. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, the Docker documentation definitely needs some clarification. Especially everything that is network-related.

Comment: thanks a lot  - the hint that boot2docker had it's own IP address was it. :)

Answer (score 1):

With boot2docker on OSX you need to set up port forwarding. You need to run something like:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port9000,tcp,,9000,,9000";
```

REF: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md

---

Also you need to replace `127.0.0.1` by `0.0.0.0` in your fig.yml file in order to have

```
- "0.0.0.0:9000:9000"
```